# Custom "Active" indicator for bootstrap NavBar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a custom nav-link indicator for the active link like [this][1] but i'm stuck on how I should go about it.

I was thinking about adding a custom `div` with the color but it doesn't make much sense to me since i'm trying to override the `active` class in bootstrap. How can I achieve this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZtP3.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix would be to create a `.current` class. Then apply the current class to the link of the page that you are on.. Something like

CSS.

```
.current{
    color:#09f;
    border-top:3px solid #09f;
}
```

**HTML - HOME PAGE  (index.html)**

```
<div class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a>
    <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
    <a href="#">EXTRA</a>
</div>
```

Then on the next page you add the class to the next link. So for page 2 it will look like this
**HTML - ABOUT  (about.html)**

```
<div class="topnav">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="#" class="current">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
    <a href="#">EXTRA</a>
</div>
```

Removed the current class from home link and added it to the second link. And on each page you add the class to the link of the page you are on.

Comment: I get that, but I meant how would I have the custom horizontal link as an indicator instead of color change?

Comment: @carlo_webber124 What do you mean horizontal link. The  border-top:3px solid #09f; will create a border at the top of the link as per your image example. Not just a colour change but also a line above the link (border)

Comment: Ah, I had missed that. Somehow. Apologies. It's alright now.